# Combine two conditions with diffrent tables MySQL

Tags: mysql, group-by, count

Can I make one query with this two conditions? And if yes, which way should I dig?

```
SELECT c.ID, c.DateEnd FROM conference c WHERE DateEnd = DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 DAY)

SELECT a.ID, a.IDConf FROM application a GROUP BY a.IDConf HAVING COUNT(a.IDConf) >= 2
```

Comment: It is far from clear what the second query is intended to do - you have a predicate based on the aggregated value of idconf but it is not aggregated in the select clause.

Comment: I have one table with conferences informations, and i have second with applications. I want to display IDConf where application is equal or more than 2 and date of end is tommorow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want join only the result for  `HAVING COUNT(a.IDConf) >= 2` you could use a inner join on subselect

```
  SELECT c.ID, c.DateEnd 
  FROM conference c 
  INNER  JOIN (
  SELECT a.ID, a.IDConf 
  FROM application a 
  GROUP BY a.IDConf 
  HAVING COUNT(a.IDConf) >= 2 
  ) t ON c.ID=t.IDConf  
   WHERE c.DateEnd = DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a left join. Try this:

```
SELECT c.ID, a.ID a_ID, c.DateEnd 
FROM conference c LEFT JOIN application a 
ON c.ID=a.IDConf
WHERE DateEnd=DATE(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 DAY))
GROUP BY c.ID, a.ID 
HAVING COUNT(a.IDConf)>=2;
```

See [MySQL Join Made Easy](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-join/) for insight on using joins.

Comment: '1  NULL 2018-03-28 ////
4  4  2018-03-28 ////
5  3  2018-03-28' But output freaky, cause first row don't need..